Is there a faster way to find max and min of $P = 4x + 2y + 3$ given $|x| + 2|y| = 4$?
Is there a faster way to find max and min of $P = 4x + 2y + 3$ given $|x| + 2|y| = 4$?
From a geometrical standpoint, the set of points that satisfy $|x| + 2|y| = 4$ is a diamond on the $Oxy$ plane.
We also have that $y = -2x + \dfrac{P-3}{2},$ which is a line with slope $-2.$ In order for this line to intersect the diamond, it must be within the lines $y = -2x + 8$ and $y = -2x -8,$ as shown in the image. Thus, $-8\leq \dfrac{P-3}{2} \leq 8,$ so we have $-13 \leq P \leq 19$.
While this argument allows me to obtain the final answer (for this multiple-choice question), it sounds a bit like "Looking at the image, we see that..." I hope to receive some help to make this argument more rigorous and also hear alternative, faster approaches.
Thank you!


$P$ is linear on each side of the polygon, therefore the extrema are attained at a corner.

Using the triangle inequality:
$$
P = 4x + 2y + 3 \le 4|x| + 2|y| + 3 
 = 19 - 6|y| \le 19 \, .
$$
Equality holds for $(x, y) = (4, 0)$, so this is the maximum.
Similarly,
$$
P = 4x + 2y + 3 \ge 3 - 4|x| - 2|y| = -13 + 6|y| \ge -13
$$
with equality for $(x, y) = (-4, 0)$.

Very nice! Thank you very much!

I don't know if this would be considered "fast," especially since it's a way to tackle many problems of this sort (that is, it has few clever insights based on this particular problem), and it is somewhat algebraically tedious, but my way would be as follows...

First, since the constraint $|x|+2|y|=4$ defines a diamond, let's parameterize it. A natural parameterization of a line between two points is
$$
(1-t)p_{\text{start}} + tp_{\text{end}} \qquad t \in [0,1]
$$
Doing this for all the corners, and shifting accordingly, we get a parameterization for $t \in [0,4]$:
$$\begin{align*}
p(t)
&= \begin{cases}
(1-t) (4,0) + t (0,2),   & t \in [0,1] \\
(1-(t-1)) (0,2) + (t-1) (-4,0),  & t \in [1,2] \\
(1-(t-2)) (-4,0) + (t-2) (0,-2),  & t \in [2,3] \\
(1-(t-3)) (0,-2) + (t-3) (4,0),  & t \in [3,4]
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
(-4t+4,2t),   & t \in [0,1] \\
(-4t+4,-2t+4),  & t \in [1,2] \\
(4t-12,-2t+4),  & t \in [2,3] \\
(4t-12,2t-8),  & t \in [3,4]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
You can play with the parameterization and see it in action in a Desmos demo here.

We have the function
$$
P(x,y) = 4x+2y+3
$$
which we want to maximize/minimize over the curve given by $\{p(t)\}_{t \in [0,4]}$. Well, the values $P$ takes on is given by the composition:
$$\begin{align*}
P(p(t))
&= \begin{cases}
4(-4t+4) + 2(2t) + 3   & t \in [0,1] \\
4(-4t+4) + 2(-2t+4) + 3,  & t \in [1,2] \\
4(4t-12) + 2(-2t+4) + 3,  & t \in [2,3] \\
4(4t-12) + 2(2t-8) + 3,  & t \in [3,4]
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
-12t+19,  & t \in [0,1] \\
-20t+27,  & t \in [1,2] \\
12t-37,  & t \in [2,3] \\
20t-61,  & t \in [3,4]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
This function is very easy to optimize. We can clearly see the function is decreasing until $t=2$, and increasing afterwards. The minimum value is hence $P(p(2)) = -13$. The maximum value then is the larger of $P(p(0))$ or $P(p(4))$, but since $p(0)=p(4)$, the value is the same either way, $19$.

Thank you very much!

Looking at the picture we can see that maximum and minimum must lie in some of the corners (or perhaps in extreme cases lie in the whole line segments).
$P$ is linear functional, so it is constant along some family of straight lines in $\mathbb R^2$. This is family of lines perpendicular to the normal vector of line $P = 0$ (by definition this is family of curves $P^{-1}(c)$ for $c \in \mathbb R$, which are lines parallel to $P=0$). Moreover this vector gives "direction of greatest change" of $P$, i.e. it lines up with the gradient of $P$.
If you are quick to find orthogonal vector and understand what it says, you can immediately point out two points which must be maximum and minimum. Otherwise you can check 4 points, which would also give you full information.

I think the OP is looking for something other than arguments involving "looking at the picture".

Thank you very much!
